# Android Exception in run Method in a Maintask

Tags: java, android, multithreading, task, runnable

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

I got a service calling the `run` method of my `MainTask` every 15 seconds (for testing reasons) `timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MainTask(), 0, 15000);` (called in `onStartCommand`.

The code in the run method is looking like this:

```
public void run() {
        Log.v("MainTask", "run() Called");
        GpsHelper gpsHelper = new GpsHelper(getApplicationContext(), this); // This is causing the error - commented out => no error
        // Doing some independent webrequests here!
        }
```

The GpsHelper class is looking like this (it has some if statements - because it is also used outside the Service in the `Mainactivity`:

```
public GpsHelper(Context context, LocationReceiver locationReceiver) {
    this.context = context;
    this.locationReceiver = locationReceiver;
    mLocationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (locationReceiver instanceof Runnable) {
        isRunnable = true;
    }
    run();
}

/**
 * Getting the Location, handling permission, requesting location updates if time is greater than 2 minutes
 */
public void getLocation() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && !isRunnable) {
        StaticHelpers.askForFineLocationPermission(context);
    } else {
        if (isRunnable && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.v("GpsHelper", "Runnable can't get position - check permissions!");
        } else {
            Location location = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            // If time not greater than 2 minutes
            // TODO: Move to resources
            if (location != null && location.getTime() > Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() - 2 * 60 * 1000) {
                Log.v("GpsHelper", "Using existing location");
                locationReceiver.onLocationAvailable(location);
            } else {
                Log.v("GpsHelper", "No Position Available => Requesting Location Updates");
                mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
                if (!isRunnable && !mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                    showSettingsDialog();
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

After getting the position this method is called: 
`mLocationManager.removeUpdates(this);`

**When is this error occurring?**
The fourth time run is getting called

**What does an possible answer need to contain?**
An answer should help me to fix this error without changing any logical behaviour and **should not run on the ui thread**!

Comment: Log.v("MainTask", "run() Called");
 GpsHelper gpsHelper = new GpsHelper(getApplicationContext(), this);  
Add this code inside a handler or runOnUiThread()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.v("MainTask", "run() Called");
            GpsHelper gpsHelper = new GpsHelper(getApplicationContext(), this); // This is causing the error - commented out => no error
        }
    });
```

Comment: I don't want to run this on the ui thread and I can not call `getActivity`

Comment: you can not update UI from a different thread. Either create a handler or runOnUiThread.

Comment: getActivity() is available in a fragment. you can replace getActivity with context of activity.